# Remove keys' quotes of a dictionary in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am creating this dictionary in the view :

```
[{'data': [[1487635200000.0, 665270], [1487376000000.0, 665073]],
'name': 'page_fans'
},
{'data': [[1487635200000.0, 170100], [1487376000000.0, 170100]],
'name': 'page_posts_impressions'
}]
```

I would like to pass it to my javascript code in the template, i need to have it in this format :

```
[{data: [[1487635200000.0, 665270], [1487376000000.0, 665073]],
name: 'page_fans'
},
{data: [[1487635200000.0, 170100], [1487376000000.0, 170100]],
name: 'page_posts_impressions'
}]
```

Basically, how can I remove the quotes only from the keys ? (note that i need to keep the quotes for the name value).

Comment: You *need* to have it in that format? Why do you *need* that?

Comment: I am using a JS library that cannot deal with the quotes. The only solution I found is creating the JS variable from a loop in the template.

Comment: Can you show us what you're doing in your template?

Comment: You can't have non-quoted string literals in javascript - what you probably want is json.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need that. JS is quite capable of dealing with quoted keys.

But what you actually do need is JSON. You should dump your data to JSON before sending to the template, and convert it back in the JS.